# Can't stop refreshing even with e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation and ive also tried to do it using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Here is my code for login page

```
import { useState } from "react";
import IsEmail from "isemail";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import m from "../library/magic-client";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const Login = () => {
  const [userMsg, setUserMsg] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();
  const [_document, set_document] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    set_document(document);
  }, []);

  if (_document) {
    _document.getElementById("searchForm").addEventListener(
      "submit",
      function (e) {
        search(document.getElementById("searchText"));
        e.preventDefault();
      },
      false
    );
  }

  const handleOnChangeEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      // Cancel the default action, if needed
      e.preventDefault();
      // Trigger the button element with a click
      document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
    }
    setUserMsg("");
    console.log("event", e);
    const email = e.target.value;
    setEmail(email);
  };
  const handleLoginWithEmail = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      // Cancel the default action, if needed
      e.preventDefault();
      // Trigger the button element with a click
      document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
    }

    if (email) {
      if (IsEmail.validate(email)) {
        //router.push("/")
        try {
          setIsLoading(true);
          const didToken = await m.auth.loginWithMagicLink({ email });
          console.log({ didToken });
          if (didToken) {
            setIsLoading(false);
            router.push("/");
          }
        } catch {
          // Handle errors if required!
          console.error("something went wrong logging in");
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
      } else {
        setUserMsg("Enter a valid email address");
      }
    } else {
      //show usermssg
      setUserMsg("Enter an email address");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="bg-[url('/static/bglg.jpg')] flex items-stretch flex-col h-screen w-full"
      id="searchForm"
    >
      <head>
        <title>SiteName SignIn</title>
      </head>
      <header className="text-4xl px-10 py-2 font-black">
        <span className="text-indigo-700">SiteName</span>
      </header>
      <div className="w-full max-w-xs m-auto bg-[#C9C9C9] rounded p-5 bg-opacity-50 border-gray-200">
        <header>
          <div className="text-indigo-700 font-black text-3xl py-2">
            <p>{isLoading ? "Loading" : "Sign In"}</p>
          </div>
        </header>
        <form className="py-5">
          <div>
            <label className="block mb-2 text-indigo-500" for="username">
              Email
            </label>
            <input
              className="w-full p-2 mb-6 text-indigo-700 border-b-2 border-indigo-500 outline-none focus:bg-gray-300"
              type="text"
              name="username"
              placeholder="Email Address"
              onChange={handleOnChangeEmail}
            />
            <div className="block mb-2 text-red-700">
              <p>{userMsg}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              className="w-full bg-indigo-700 hover:bg-pink-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 mb-6 rounded"
              type="button"
              value={isLoading ? "Loading" : "Sign In"}
              id="myBtn"
              onClick={handleLoginWithEmail}
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

There also seems to be some hydration error because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, causing the entire root will switch to client rendering. And this was happening way before i used any libraries if that is important.

My directories is from default create-next-app using npx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a lot of unnecessary code and a memory leak. I suspect this is partly why your code isn't working "as expected."

Everything I'm doing below is using [default HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#inappropriate-for-the-control) - that link has examples for on submit, required, autocomplete, and anything a form can do.

---

Your memory leak is caused by creating an event listener and not cleaning it up when the component unmounts.

You can prevent the memory leak by using the default HTML `form` `onSubmit` event listener and removing your custom event listener.

#### Remove:

```
  const [_document, set_document] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    set_document(document);
  }, []);

  if (_document) {
    _document.getElementById("searchForm").addEventListener(
      "submit",
      function (e) {
        search(document.getElementById("searchText"));
        e.preventDefault();
      },
      false
    );
  }
```

#### Add:

```
<form onSubmit={handleLoginWithEmail}>...
```

---

You can replace the `Enter` key check with a submit button that responds to the `enter` key press by default.

#### Remove:

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
if (e.key === "Enter") {
 e.preventDefault();
 document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
}
```

#### Add:

```
<form ...>
 <button type="submit">log in</button>
</form>
```

---

#### All together:

I removed code that isn't relevant to make it cleaner.

You can clean up your checks by taking most of them out of `if/else` and making them `if` by utilizing `return`. You also have the opportunity for your loader never to stop, and it should be moved out of `catch` to `finally` so it's always called.

Also, iOS requires the `action` `form` attribute to be set, or it won't show the submit button on the on-screen keyboard.

```
const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [userMsg, setUserMsg] = useState("");
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleOnChangeEmail = (e) => {
    setUserMsg("");
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!email) return setUserMsg("Enter an email address");
    if (!IsEmail.validate(email)) return setUserMsg("Enter an email address");
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const didToken = await m.auth.loginWithMagicLink({ email });
      if (didToken) router.push("/");
    } catch {
      console.error("Error logging in");
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form action="#" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        autoComplete="username"
        name="username"
        onChange={handleOnChangeEmail}
        required
        type="text"
      />
      <button type="submit" disabled={isLoading}>
        {isLoading ? "Loading" : "Sign In"}
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank youuuu. I am newbie and what you have explained i can understand well. You literally made my day.